# Image editing library crashes on devices running nougat

Tags: android, build.gradle, compatibility, renderscript

We're using a library to edit images. It works fine on devices running marshmallow and previous versions of Android but crashes on Android 7.0 with this error:

`AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-56
Process: com.neon.android, PID: 21869
android.support.v8.renderscript.RSRuntimeException: Loading of ScriptC script failed.
at android.support.v8.renderscript.ScriptC.<init>(ScriptC.java:61)`

However, the above error was addressed by setting these values to various properties in the build.gradle file and manifest:

```
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'
renderscriptTargetApi 23
android:targetSdkVersion="25"
```

As a result of the above changes,the app works on 7.0 but crashes on all other versions of Android. How do i ensure that the library works on other versions as well?

If this helps in any way- the old values:

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"
renderscriptTargetApi 20
android:targetSdkVersion="22"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was with the `targetSdkVersion`. Was targeting only 7.0 devices. Solved it by changing it to 22. Other values remain the same.

```
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'
renderscriptTargetApi 23
```